# JavaScript check file extension for multiple uploads

Tags: javascript

I have contact form, and Js which validates the size of selected files. Also I want to add extension check. My code so far is

```
var inputs = $('input[type="file"]')
inputs.on('change', function () {
    var size = 0;

    inputs.each(function () {
        $.each(this.files, function () {
            size += this.size;
            var names = [];
           
            alert(x);

        });
    });

    if (size > 19000000) {
        alert('Ukupna dozvoljena veličina fajlova za upload je 20mb!');
        $('.inputDugme').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.inputDugme').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }
});
```

Is there I way to get extension of files, and save it in array. And then check content of array.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i created undo for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect extension names like this:

```
var size = 0,
    etx = [];

inputs.each(function () {
    $.each(this.files, function () {
        size += this.size;
        ext.push(this.name.split('.').pop());
    });
});
```

`x[] = this.name;` is not valid syntax in Javascript, you should use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

Comment: could u help me to check array for valid extensions i find something like this  var a = $.inArray('mp4', ext) ? but i always get -1

Comment: What extensions are valid? Where do you store them in another array?

Comment: can you show me the way how to compare ti ext array with, array with allowed extension for example allowed= ['jpg','bmp','gif']

Comment: Check this code: `etx.forEach(function(e) { console.log(allowed.indexOf(e)) })` to check every extension from `etx` array.

Answer (score 0):

**try this.**

`var ext = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];`